# How to play full-length songs on Android using SpotifySDK

Tags: spotify

I read everywhere that it is possible to offer the users of our applications full-length songs via using Spotify SDK for Android. But only way I could find is that users should have premium account on Spotify to get full-length tracks. Otherwise, it is not possible to get full-length even if you were non-premium user of Spotify.

Am I wrong or right? Is there a way to get full-length tracks without being a premium user on Spotify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But only way I could find is that users should have premium account on
>   Spotify to get full-length tracks.

Correct. Spotify's Developer site's documentation about the [Android SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/) states,

> Please also note that streaming of full-length tracks is only
>   available to your users who have a Spotify Premium subscription.

Users are required to have premium accounts since the Android SDK allows the user to select tracks to play on-demand. The rules for free users are very different. For example, free users cannot play any track they want in the mobile application, but are forced to shuffle a context like a playlist or an album. Free users also have to listen to advertisements in-between tracks. The Android SDK simply doesn't support this.

Comment: Is there a way to shuffle a playlist with the Android Spotify Sdk? (without having a premium account)